# Как парсить данные страницы, если они генерируются на клиенте?

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер, http

Всем привет, в общем нужно мне спарсить данные о количестве билетов с сайта rzd. Я попробовал через их api, но ничего не работает, поэтом решил тупо парсить код страницы. Юзаю nodejs и request. Проблема в том, что данные (как я понял) генеряться на клиенте, а в коде страницы их нет. Можете подсказать как быть?

```
var request = require('request');
var URL = 'https://pass.rzd.ru/tickets/public/ruSTRUCTURE_ID=704&refererPageId=4065&layer_name=e3-route&tfl=3&st0=%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%9A%D0%92%D0%90+%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%92%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%A6%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%AF+(%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%92%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%A6%D0%9A%D0%98%D0%99+%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%97%D0%90%D0%9B)&code0=2000005&dt0=14.07.2018&st1=%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%92+1+%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A1&code1=2020000&checkSeats=1';
var pagecode = '';
req = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: URL,
};
request(req, function (error, response, pagecode) {
    var k = pagecode.indexOf('route-cartype-places-left');
    var tickets = pagecode.substr(k, 70);
    console.log(tickets);
  });
```

Данный код просто хватает название класса (где-то около этого класса есть нужные данные) и выводит 70 символов после, получается это:

```
route-cartype-places-left">Мест: {{freeSeats}}
                                                </span>
                                                {{/
```

Вместо "{{freeSeats}}" должно быть число, как его получить?
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Вы достаете только разметку страницы, все данные о маршрутах, местах и билетах летают на pass.rzd.ru через websocket соединение и дальше уже js-ом вставляются в нужные места страницы. Чтобы парсить готовую страницу  — вам нужно не просто получить её html код, а запустить и javascript в том числе. Смотрите в сторону PhantomJS и работы с ним. Логичнее было бы не парсить весь код страницы, а перехватывать сообщения из websocket, ибо там летает json с нужными вам данными.

Comment: PhantomJS - прошлый век) Советую почитать про headless browsers, я был на конференции HolyJS Moscow 2017, там чувак профессионально занимается парсингом сайтов и скачиванием видео с сайтов.

Вот полное видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nn75sRAOlIY

Если хочешь заниматься парсингом, то делай это правильно)